# Exception safety C++ shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, exception-safety

I try to implement a JSON framework in C++ and want to make use of polymorphic concepts. I have a class `JSONNode` which is kind of container that stores other JSONNode objects itself and so on. I am doing this with pointers and dynamic allocation. For exception safety I do not want to use `new/delete` but go with boost shared pointer. A basic scenario for adding an element (a further json object) to a json object looks like this:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<JSONNode> JSONNodePtr;   

void JSONNode::Add(JSONNodePtr nodePtr, const std::string& name)
{
    this->elements[name] = nodePtr;  // store in STL std::map
}

// create and add json object 
JSONNodePtr obj(new JSONNode());
JSONNodePtr element(new JSONNode());
obj->Add(element, "firstElement");
```

For easier use I would rather do it without explicit allocation of `element` and put the creation of the shared pointer into the class method `Add`:

```
void JSONNode::Add(JSONNode* node, const std::string& name)
{
    JSONNodePtr nodePtr(node);
    this->elements[name] = nodePtr;
}

// create and add json object 
...
obj->Add(new JSONNode, "firstElement");
```

But is that still exception safe? I guess not because the creation of the shared pointer is not immediately done with the allocation of the JSONNode*. What do you think? Or are there other more common ways to implement this?

Comment: See `make_shared` for another "common way" to ensure exception-safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is that still exception safe?

No. If the construction of the `string` to pass as the other argument to `Add` throws, then the dynamic object may be leaked. It is unspecified which argument is created first.

The original code ensures that the dynamic object is assigned to a smart pointer before anything else happens: the only thing that could fail is the creation of the smart pointer itself, in which case it will delete the object.

> Or are there other more common ways to implement this?

It's generally a better idea to use the `make_shared` function template, rather than using `new` yourself. Not only does it guarantee exception safety by never exposing a naked pointer, it also makes more efficient use of memory by creating the controlled object and the shared reference count in a single block of memory.

```
obj->Add(boost::make_shared<JSONNode>(), "firstElement"); // or std:: in C++11
```

Comment: Ok. If I change the string parameter "name" to be given by value what involves a copy constructor within the function call - would that change things as the copy constructor might fail?

Comment: @MichiMichbeck: Actually, my answer is wrong: I didn't notice that you were creating a string.